# jqGrid issue with IE11 - First key enter ignore when user tab out from editable cell

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, internet-explorer-11

I am facing a weird issue in IE11, where it is ignoring the first typed character in editable cell.
Use case is, when user enter some data in jqGrid cell and press <kbd>TAB</kbd>, then we make same cell editable again. And issue is, when cell become editable again, it always ignores first typed character.

```
var mydata = [{
    name: "Toronto",
    country: "Canada",
    continent: "North America"
}, {
    name: "New York City",
    country: "USA",
    continent: "North America"
}, {
    name: "Silicon Valley",
    country: "USA",
    continent: "North America"
}, {
    name: "Paris",
    country: "France",
    continent: "Europe"
}]

var gridCtrl = $("#grid").jqGrid({
    data: mydata,
    datatype: "local",
    colNames: ["Name", "Country", "Continent"],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'name',
        index: 'name',
        editable: true,
    }, {
        name: 'country',
        index: 'country',
        editable: true,
    }, {
        name: 'continent',
        index: 'continent',
        editable: true,
    }],
    pager: '#pager',    
    cellEdit: true,
    cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
    afterEditCell: GridAfterEditCell,
    beforeSaveCell: GridBeforeSaveCell,
    afterRestoreCell: GridAfterRestoreCell,
    afterSaveCell: GridAfterSaveCell
});

function GridAfterEditCell(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
}

function GridAfterSaveCell(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
}

function GridBeforeSaveCell(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {    
    alert('some validation alert!!!');
    setTimeout(function(){
        // refocus on the same cell
        gridCtrl.jqGrid('editCell', rowid, iCol, true);
    }, 10);
    return value;    
}

function GridAfterRestoreCell(rowid, value, iRow, iCol) {    
}
```

Here is jsfiddle code link: 
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CzVVK/2225/

Steps:

1. Open the link in IE11
2. Enter the data first cell
3. Press the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key
4. It will show the alert and make the same cell editable again
5. Now press any key (i.e. type character <kbd>a</kbd>)
6. You will notice first character you entered, is ignored!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use old jqGrid 4.6 in your demo. It's the bug, which is fixed in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). Look at the modified demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/CzVVK/2230/. The new demo uses URLs of free jqGrid 4.10.0 from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)).

I fixed the code of `beforeSaveCell` callback additionally to use `iRow` instead of `rowid`, which you used as the parameter of `editCell`:

```
function GridBeforeSaveCell(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {    
    var $grid = $(this);
    alert('some validation alert!!!');
    setTimeout(function(){
        // refocus on the same cell
        $grid.jqGrid('editCell', iRow, iCol, true);
    }, 10);
    return value;    
}
```

Comment: Do you have any link for the bug? Just wanted to see the details. And thanks for pointing it out the free jqGrid.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You have already the demo which reproduces the bug and you can see that the bug is fixed in free jqGrid. All changes you can find on GitHub. Starting with the fork free jqGrid I posted more as 870 commits compared with jqGrid 4.7 (see [the statistic](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/graphs/commit-activity)). If you compare with jqGrid 4.6 it will be more. I remind me about the bug and that I fixed it, but I can't point you to exact commit from the 870 posted. Sorry.

Comment: Yes it works. I was curious about the root cause of this issue.

Comment: @neeraj: It I remind me correctly it was something with correct processing of `keydown` (not `keypress`), but I don't remind me more exactly now.

Comment: @neeraj: You can see all the changes between jqGrid 4.6 and the current state of free jqGrid [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/compare/v4.6.0...master). It's more as 1000 changes. You can use other tools of GitHub to analyse detailed the changes of `grid.celledit.js` only. The problem is in changing formatting of the code. The old code had no common JavaScript style and the code of free jqGrid is reformatted and many variables are renamed to hold common name conversion. It makes comparing of the code with old version complex.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes, there are lot of changes, I was going through commit logs.